# How to restrict editing SP Items from SharePoint UI?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I am making powerapps on SP Online, and I want users to only view and edit items via powerapps, and not from the SP UI. I am following 3 tutorials here

https://michelcarlo.com/2021/05/30/steps-to-deny-power-apps-users-access-to-sharepoint-data-from-the-sharepoint-ui/

https://ashiqf.com/2020/01/19/restricting-power-apps-users-from-viewing-or-updating-the-sharepoint-list-content-from-sharepoint-gui/

https://blog.josephvelliah.com/restrict-smart-users-data-entry-on-sharepoint-list-associated-with-powerapps-app

I tried to make a copy of contribute and remove the "view application pages" and then set an account to that. However that account could still edit items in the list from the SP UI.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, in addition to grant users with custom permission, you should also activate the "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode" feature in the site collection features.

Here is a [same question](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/531034/how-to-restrict-editing-sp-items-from-sharepoint-o.html?childToView=532744#answer-532744) in the Microsoft forum.

---

Update:

You could go to list settings to set unique permission for users. Here're steps.

(1)Go to Site settings -> Site permissions -> Create group -> Choose the custom permission you created before(PowerApps) as the permission for the group.

(2)Add users into this newly created group.

(3)Add users into default SharePoint Visitors group.

(4)Go to List settings -> Permissions for this list

(5)Stop Inheriting Permissions

(6)Remove default SharePoint Visitors group

Comment: But the users also need read access to the site and other lists.

Comment: Based on your description, I understand that you want to users restrict editing SharePoint items from UI only for some lists. Is it right? I have updated the answer, please check.